# Refresh list in Material 3

Tags: android, material-design

I have an Android app that displays a list or grid of cards, depending on the screen size, that is loaded from the backend. I migrated it to the Material 3 spec recently.

The app currently does automatic refresh of the list on open and force refresh on swipe. I can’t quite find the info about [swipe to refresh gesture](https://m2.material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-swipe-to-refresh.html#usage) in Material 3 spec, only in Material 2, is it not supposed to be used in Material 3? If so, what is a preferable way to refresh the list?

I can probably can add a button to the top bar for the force refresh

Answer (score 1):

In Material Design 3, the **swipe-to-refresh gesture** has been replaced with a new **pull-to-refresh interaction** that follows a more consistent and predictable motion. This new interaction is based on the same underlying principles as the previous swipe-to-refresh gesture, but with a more natural and intuitive motion that aligns with the latest design trends.

To implement the pull-to-refresh interaction in your app, you can use the new Refresh Control component introduced in Material Design 3. This component provides a simple, intuitive way for users to refresh content in your app by pulling down on the screen.

Besides, you can read more about pull-to-refresh interaction in this article: https://blog.icons8.com/articles/pull-to-refresh-ui-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like MD3 isn't massively concerned about inputs and interactions at all, outside of how they change button states. Pull to refresh remains a useful and well-supported pattern on mobile devices.